# Meaning of multiple markes in this line?

Tags: java

```
package Zote;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;
       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
         name = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Your name is"  + name);
    }    
}
```

I get an error on Scanner but the program still run? an Error display like triangle orange sign......please help me

Comment: What do the errors say? When I put your code in my ide i don't get any errors. Also just a heads up packages should be lowercase by convention

Comment: Multiple marker at this line ,Resource leak: 'input' is never closed

Comment: Ok well thats not exactly an error just a warning. What you need to do is add a line closing your scanner so that java can give those resources back since youre not using them anymore. The code would be `input.close();`

Comment: Thank you all@ArachnidHivemind

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about this error on the left:

[image]

That isn't as much of an error as it is a warning. If you want to know why the warning is there it is because the main method is "static" and since you aren't changing the input scanner it wants you to make the input variable as static outside of the main method like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
private static Scanner input;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
   input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name:");
     name = input.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Your name is"  + name);
   }    
}
```

Basically, the only errors that you should worry about now are the red exclamation points.